# Showing $Y'$ is isomorphic to $Y''$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $W$ and $Y$ be subspaces of $V$ satisfying $W+Y=V$. Let $Y'$ be a complement of $Y$ in $V$ and let $Y''$ be a complement of $W\cap Y$ in $W$. Show that $Y'$ is isomorphic to $Y''$.

This is where I'm at so far:

Let $Y'$ be the complement of $Y$ in $V$.

$$[(V=Y \oplus Y'): V=Y+Y, Y \cap Y'={0_V}]$$

Let $Y''$ be a complement of $W$ intersect $Y$ in $W$. So, ($W=(W \cap Y) \oplus Y''$)

$V=Y \oplus Y'=((W \cap Y)\oplus Y'')+Y$ , every $u$ element of $Y''$, then $u=u_1+u_2$, where $u_1$ is in $Y$ and $u_2$ is in $Y'$

How do I construct $\alpha:Y''\to Y'$  and $\alpha(u)=u_2$

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$Y'\cong\frac{W+Y}{Y}\cong\frac W{W\cap Y}\cong Y''$
where the middle isomorphism is one of the three canonical isomorphism; it's induced by $W\hookrightarrow W+Y\twoheadrightarrow\frac{W+Y}{Y}$ which is onto and has kernel $W\cap Y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can take a complement $W'$ of $W$ such that $W'\subseteq Y$.
Then we have $Y\ =\ (Y\cap W)\oplus W'$, and
$$ V\ =\ Y\oplus Y'\ =\ (Y\cap W)\oplus W'\oplus Y' \\
 V\ =\ W\oplus W'\ =\ (Y\cap W)\oplus Y''\oplus W'\,. $$